# ASP .NET Core https rewrite does not seem to work

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

Env: ASP.NET Core 2.0. App gets deployed to IIS on Windows Server 2016.

In my startup.cs, I have the following code:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
  ...
  services.Configure<MvcOptions>(options => {
      options.Filters.Add(new RequireHttpsAttribute());
  });
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env) {
   ...
   var options = new RewriteOptions().AddRedirectToHttps();
   app.UseRewriter(options);
}
```

However, when the app is deployed to IIS, I do not see `http://xxx` getting changed to `https://xxx` in the browser.

I can directly go to `https://xxx` and that seems to work. However, the idea is to automatically redirect http requests to https.

What is it that I am missing? Do I need to do something on IIS as well? Regards.

Comment: Why are you using both the middleware and the attribute? You only need one.

Answer (score 2):

From the code snippet you posted looks like `app.UseRewriter(options);` is the last in the `Configure()` method. Move `app.UseMvc();` to the very bottom of the method, since sort order in the pipeline is very important. I suspect MVC processes your request before the rewrite rule is actually applied.

Also:

- You might not need `RequireHttpsAttribute` -- run your code without the filter, the HTTPS redirect should still happen.
- This might depend on your requirements, however I normally set 301 (permanent) redirect to HTTPS. There is an extension for that `AddRedirectToHttpsPermanent()`.

Comment: I think this is the answer, too. Middleware in .NET Core acts like a pipeline for requests to be dealt with. Any item in the pipleline can generate a response, and the MVC middleware will be generating the response and sending it out.